defining nested Objects in schema using mongoose
models.movies.js:
const mongoose=require("mongoose")

const likesModel=require("./models.like")

const moviesSchema=mongoose.Schema({
    _id:{
        type:Number,
        require:true
    },
    movieName:String,
    movieUrl:String,
    moviePosterUrl:String,
    movieCast:[String],
    like:[likesModel]
})

const MovieModel=mongoose.model("Movie",moviesSchema)
module.exports=MovieModel

models.like.js
const mongoose=require("mongoose")
const userModel=require("../models/models.UserModel")

const likeSchema=mongoose.Schema({
    _id:{
        type:Number,
        require:true
    },
    noOfLikes:{
        type:Number,
    },
    likeduser: userModel
})

const LikesModel=mongoose.model("Like",likeSchema)
module.exports=LikesModel

model.UserModel.js
const mongoose=require("mongoose")

const RegisterSchema=mongoose.Schema({
    _id:{
        type:Number,
        required:true
    },
    email:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    password:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    username:String,
    phone:Number,
    role:String,
    active:Boolean
})

const RegisterModel=mongoose.model("register",RegisterSchema)
module.exports=RegisterModel

I am getting the error mentioned in the picture (https://i.sstatic.net/kVNZA5b8.png)
Can someone help me solve it

Welcome to StackOverflow. Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question. Read: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example. Format your code and make use of block quotes ```like this```.

There are many issues in your code. Would you like an answer with suggestions of how to fix them?

In your model.like.js you are importing const userModel=require("../models/models.UserModel") but your imported file name should be model.UserModel.js as per the file-name provided by you in question.

Please review the schematypes, like and likeduser, in moviesSchema and likeSchema respectively. The type “likesModel” given in like is invalid. Similarly, the type “userModel” given in likeduser is also invalid.
These two invalid types are the source of the issue.
It is invalid because, userModel and likeduser are the model objects, However schema objects are allowed.
Please review the error message under this context.
TypeError: Invalid schema configuration: `model` is not a valid type within the array..

Therefore please refer to the schema objects, likesSchema and RegisterSchema instead.
The code corrected may look like this:
const moviesSchema=mongoose.Schema({
…
    like:[likesSchema]
})

const likeSchema=mongoose.Schema({ _id:{ type:Number, require:true }, noOfLikes:{ type:Number, }, likeduser: RegisterSchema })

Note:
At present these schema objects are not exported from their respective modules, please export it as well and then import the same for referencing.

Thanks to Voters. Request if possible, please leave a comment as well, I am willing to improve this post as you may suggest.
